# Is there a possible way to track when a boolean initially turn true in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, datetime, boolean

I have a boolean column in my table and a datetime related to it. I want to be able to track down when the boolean initially turns true. In the model I have tried

```
def example
  if boolean_field == true
   datetime_field = time.now
  end
end
```

but the problem with that is when the boolean is set to true, the datetime_field will keep updating everytime i reload the page or database since the boolean will always be in a constant state of true. I have also try to use rails dirty on it with:

```
boolean_field_changed?
```

but that method doesn't seems to update the datetime column at all. 
P.S i do have a before_save callback on the method.

```
 def returned_time
    if self.returned?
      returned_at = Time.now
    end
 end


 before_save :returned_time
```

any help on how i can save the initial time once the boolean_field changes from false to true will be much appreciated.  thanks in advance

Comment: This process changed in the new version of Rails.  What version of Rails are you using?

Comment: @TomAranda sorry for the late reply, but I am currently using  rails 5

Comment: If this is being called with `boolean_field_changed?` _before_ save, then yes I imagine that would prevent the `datetime_field` from updating, as it does not yet know that the boolean field changed.

Comment: oh the before_save is being called on the method "example" which contains the block of code @inveterateliterate

Comment: Can you post the code you use to generate the `before_save` callback?

Comment: @TomAranda I have updated my code

Comment: Question answered.

Answer (score 1):

If `returned` is a boolean column in your table, then you should not need [ActiveModel::Dirty](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Dirty.html).  That module is for adding change detection for non-database attributes.  You should be able to use Active Record's built-in `changed?` method:

```
class MyModel < Application Record

  before_save :returned_time

  def returned_time
    if self.returned? and self.returned_changed?
      self.returned_at = Time.now
    end
  end

end
```

This will update the `returned_at` time if `returned` is true and if that field has changed.  This may suit your business logic.

However, if your goal is to only update the `returned_at` field when a book has been returned, you may want to check for the presence of a `returned_at` date instead:

```
def returned_time
  if self.returned? and self.returned_at.blank?
    self.returned_at = Time.now
  end
end
```

This will only update the date if the book has been returned and there is no return date.

One final note, the `self` before `returned_at` in `self.returned_at = Time.now` is important.  Otherwise, the field may not get updated.

Comment: thank you. that definetely fixed it. appreciated it. @TomAranda

Comment: I have tried but unfortunately SO won't let me vote it since i am below reputation 15 :/. when i do get above, i will vote on it :)

Comment: my mistake i have misread the message. the Vote is recorded but won't be displayed publicly since I am below 15 reputation. Thanks for the help though